# Using Interop.Word, is there a way to do a replace (using Find.Execute) and keep the original text's justification?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, word-automation

I'm attempting to write find/replace code for Word documents using Word Automation through Interop.Word (11.0).  My documents all have various fields (that don't show up in Document.Fields) that are surrounded with brackets, eg., `<DATE>` needs to be replaced with `DateTime.Now.Format("MM/dd/yyyy")`.  The find/replace works fine.  However, some of the text being replaced is right-justified, and upon replacement, the text wraps to the next line.  Is there any way that I can keep the justification when I perform the replace?  Code is below:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Application wordApp = null;
try
{
    wordApp = new Word.Application {Visible = false};
    //.... open the document ....
    object unitsStory = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
    object moveType = Word.WdMovementType.wdMove;
    wordApp.Selection.HomeKey(ref unitsStory, ref moveType);
    wordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();  //tried removing this, no luck
    object replaceTextWith = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    object textToReplace = "<DATE>";
    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    object typeMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref textToReplace, ref typeMissing, 
        ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, 
        ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, 
        ref replaceTextWith, ref replaceAll, ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing, 
        ref typeMissing, ref typeMissing);
    // ... save quit etc.... 
}
finally
{
     //clean up wordApp
}
```

TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment for alignment

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        object missing = System.Type.Missing;

        try
        {
            object fileName = @"C:\TT\change.doc";
            doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            doc.Activate();

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range tmpRange in doc.StoryRanges)
            {
                tmpRange.Find.Text = "<DATE>";
                tmpRange.Find.Replacement.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                tmpRange.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat.Alignment =
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;



                tmpRange.Find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

                tmpRange.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceAll,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }

            doc.Save();

            doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            word.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            word.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
```

Comment: After application quit release object from memory using Marshal.ReleaseComObject(your object).